# I am confused about topological sort

Tags: graph, topological-sort

I am new to graph theory and I am new to topological sort. All I know is that, to topologically sort some tasks, I have to run dfs on it and then sort the vertices according to their finishing time. Well, I have tried it. But somehow I am getting wrong answer.

Suppose for a graph with 5 vertices and 4 edges, and the edges being, 1->2, 2->3, 1->3, 1->5, my code gives the answer "4 1 5 2 3" when it should give "1 4 2 5 3". Is there anything wrong with my code or is there anything wrong with my idea of topological sort?

Here is my code.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<cstdio>
#include<stack>
#define MAX 100000

using namespace std;

vector<int> adj_list[MAX];
int f[MAX], d[MAX];//discovery time and finishing time
int color[MAX];
int time;
stack<int> stk;

void dfs(int vertex);
void dfs_visit(int u);

int main(void)
{
    freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
int vertex, edge;

//I am creating the adjacency list
cin >> vertex >> edge;
for(int i=1; i<=edge; i++)
{
    int n1, n2;
    cin >> n1 >> n2;
    adj_list[n1].push_back(n2);
}

//I am starting the depth-first-search
dfs(vertex);

return 0;
}

void dfs(int vertex)
{
    //If it's 0 then it means white
for(int i=1; i<=vertex; i++)
    if(color[i]==0) dfs_visit(i);


//Here I am printing the vertices
while(stk.size())
{
    cout << stk.top() << " ";
    stk.pop();
}
cout << endl;

return;
}

void dfs_visit(int u)
{
//If it's 1 then it means grey
color[u]=1;
d[u]=++time;

for(int i=0; i<adj_list[u].size(); i++)
{
    int v=adj_list[u][i];
    if(color[v]==0) dfs_visit(v);
}

//If it's 2 then it means black
color[u]=2;
f[u]=++time;

//I am inserting the vertex in the stack when I am finished, searching it
stk.push(u);
}
```

Comment: Asking strangers to spot errors in your code by inspection is not productive.  You should step through your code line-by-line using a debugger, and see whether its behaviour corresponds to your intention.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, i am sorry. But can you tell me what the answer would be for the graph. Please, it would be a great hope.

Comment: I'm confused.  You don't have any edges involving 4, so how can you have any preference for where it shows up?  And isn't `[4, 1, 5, 2, 3]` an equally valid sorting?  1 occurs before 2, 2 before 3, 1 before 3, and 1 before 5.

Comment: @DSM As far as  I know 4 can be at the beginning or at the end, it surely can't be in the middle can it??

Comment: @eddard.stark: there are many valid topological sorts for this graph (15, by my count).  Of those, 9 have 4 in the middle.  The graph without the `4` looks like it has 3 sorts, and there are 5 places to stick a 4, hence 15.  Since there's no edge involving 4 (equiv: it doesn't matter when 4 occurs), it can be anywhere.

Comment: @DSM I just figured out what you meant. Thanks a lot. It's just that I read it in the Cormen book. And there they said to just sort the finishing time. But actual topological sort can have 4 in the middle. Thanks :D

Comment: @DSM can you make that an answer?